# How to test if my implementation of tree/graph data structures are correct?

Tags: graphs, trees, software-testing, testing

I've recently implemented RB tree, B-Tree and vEB tree. I was wondering however if there's any rule of thumb for testing if my implementation are actually correct.

Is there any reference that can tell how to develop proper test cases for such data structures?

Besides from mathematical techniques maybe.

What about graph in general?

Answer (score 2):

Identify the [representation invariants](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse331/11wi/conceptual-info/abstraction-functions-and-rep-invariants.html).  Add assert statements to [check that the representation invariant holds](http://web.mit.edu/6.031/www/sp17/classes/13-abstraction-functions-rep-invariants/) (sometimes called a [repOK](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2002sp/lectures/rec08.htm) function).  Use [random testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_testing) to generate millions of test cases, and check that no assert ever fires.

Build a reference implementation of the abstract data type that implements all of the methods, but instead of using your data structure, implements the same semantics using some known-good data structure (e.g., a simple list or something).  Use [random testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_testing) to generate millions of test cases, and check that in every case your implementation produces the same results as the reference implementation.

This isn't perfect but it'll probably be pretty good.

Comment: Can you be more specific for example with the red-black tree and, maybe harder, the vEB tree?

Comment: @user8469759, No, because this answer isn't specific to red-black trees or vEB trees, so I don't see anything to be more specific about.  Was there anything in particular that you found unclear about the suggestions in my answer?

Comment: I just can't see the invariants I should test for the cases in my question.

Comment: @user8469759, test all of them.  If you are asking what are the invariants of a red-black tree, or of a vEB tree, I suggest you ask that separately (one question per data structure, please) -- but make sure to first put some thought into it, do some searching, and list all the invariants you've been able to come up with on your own.  You might find that with a combination of searching + thought on your own you can come up with the invariants.  For instance, the invariants of a red-black tree are usually listed as part of its definition.